# Multiple property encryption using jasypt encryption

Tags: encryption, spring-boot, password-encryption, jasypt

I have relatively less idea about encryption but i have done research on encryption in spring boot in application.properties file but i have not found any material based on multiple password encryption.If someone could provide some material or some direction as to how i would proceed will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you got to do 3 things.
 1. Encrypt your password using jasypt.This can be done using command line tool as indicated [here](http://www.jasypt.org/cli.html) or using a simple java program as indicated [here](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-texts.html). You need a password along with the string you need to encrypt. password is something like a secret key(or salt) which is used to encrypt the string you want to encrypt.
 2. Add this to your application properties or yml `jasypt.encryptor.password=password_used_in_the_previous_step`
 3. And add the encrypted password you got from step 1 like this `ENC(Your_Encrypted_Password)`

Add the necessary dependencies.

Here is a good example.

https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot.

Comment: i got the direction i needed.Cheers!

Comment: I didn't understand how this helps for multiple passwords.